# CoordinatorLayout custom behavior with AppBarLayout

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

I am trying to achieve a similar behavior to that of Telegram, on the settings page, that is, there is a CircleImage that when scrolling up goes to the left of the Topbar title, and when scrolling down goes to the middle of the expanded AppBarLayout.

[image]

I was basing my work on this example:

https://github.com/saulmm/CoordinatorBehaviorExample

But in this case the original coder is recreating the Topbar twice. I dont want to do that, the default behavior of the topbar is what I need and also I want to take advantage of the hamburger menu and the options menu that come out of the box.

This is my view hierarchy:

```
DrawerLayout
  |
  |---CoordinatorLayout
       |--AppBarLayout
       |    |-CollapsingToolbarLayout
       |        |-ImageView (backdrop image)
       |        |-Toolbar
       |--NestedScrollView
       |--ImageView (circleimage avatar)
```

As you can see I cannot make the Toolbar layout a sibling of my CircleImage so I cannot bind them together on the `layoutDependsOn` method. I tried binding to the AppBarLayout basing my code off the one on the github repo but to be honest I cannot make much sense of what's happening in the original code.

Comment: Check this out: http://saulmm.github.io/mastering-coordinator and scroll over to *Custom Behavior* Heading, You will find your intended behavior.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

My behavior was implemented in much the same manner as Saul's.  The biggest difference is that I like to put a non-visible view like a `Space` where I wanted the circle image to end up, then use that view's bounds to determine how to move & size the circle image.

```
public class CollapsingImageBehavior extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<View> {

    private final static int X = 0;
    private final static int Y = 1;
    private final static int WIDTH = 2;
    private final static int HEIGHT = 3;

    private int mTargetId;

    private int[] mView;

    private int[] mTarget;

    public CollapsingImageBehavior() {
    }

    public CollapsingImageBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

        if (attrs != null) {
            TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CollapsingImageBehavior);
            mTargetId = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.CollapsingImageBehavior_collapsedTarget, 0);
            a.recycle();
        }

        if (mTargetId == 0) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("collapsedTarget attribute not specified on view for behavior");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, View child, View dependency) {
        return dependency instanceof AppBarLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, View child, View dependency) {

        setup(parent, child);

        AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) dependency;

        int range = appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange();
        float factor = -appBarLayout.getY() / range;

        int left = mView[X] + (int) (factor * (mTarget[X] - mView[X]));
        int top = mView[Y] + (int) (factor * (mTarget[Y] - mView[Y]));
        int width = mView[WIDTH] + (int) (factor * (mTarget[WIDTH] - mView[WIDTH]));
        int height = mView[HEIGHT] + (int) (factor * (mTarget[HEIGHT] - mView[HEIGHT]));

        CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams lp = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
        lp.width = width;
        lp.height = height;
        child.setLayoutParams(lp);
        child.setX(left);
        child.setY(top);

        return true;
    }

    private void setup(CoordinatorLayout parent, View child) {

        if (mView != null) return;

        mView = new int[4];
        mTarget = new int[4];

        mView[X] = (int) child.getX();
        mView[Y] = (int) child.getY();
        mView[WIDTH] = child.getWidth();
        mView[HEIGHT] = child.getHeight();

        View target = parent.findViewById(mTargetId);
        if (target == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("target view not found");
        }

        mTarget[WIDTH] += target.getWidth();
        mTarget[HEIGHT] += target.getHeight();

        View view = target;
        while (view != parent) {
            mTarget[X] += (int) view.getX();
            mTarget[Y] += (int) view.getY();
            view = (View) view.getParent();
        }

    }
}
```

And here's the layout.  One important thing I found out is that the circle image view needed to have an elevation set so that it would lay out atop the toolbar in collapsed mode, otherwise it would be behind the toolbar and not shown.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.krislarson.customcoordinatorlayoutbehavior.ScrollingActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="280dp"
            android:minHeight="108dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:title="Abby"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleGravity="center_horizontal"
            app:expandedTitleMarginTop="140dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/background"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/sunset"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

                <Space
                    android:id="@+id/circle_collapsed_target"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"/>

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_scrolling"/>

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/circle_image_view"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:src="@drawable/abby"
        android:layout_marginTop="220dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        app:border_color="@android:color/black"
        app:border_width="2dp"
        app:collapsedTarget="@id/circle_collapsed_target"
        app:layout_behavior="com.krislarson.customcoordinatorlayoutbehavior.CollapsingImageBehavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

You can see the entire demo project at https://github.com/klarson2/CustomCoordinatorLayoutBehavior

Comment: I'll need to tweak the layout a bit, the circle image starts out in different places pre vs post lollipop.

Comment: what is <include layout="@layout/content_scrolling"/> ??  andtools:context="com.krislarson.customcoordinatorlayoutbehavior.ScrollingActivity"> ??

Comment: It includes the scrolling view that drives the nested scroll.  If you select the "Scrolling Activity" template when creating a new project, you get this XML file (`activity_scrolling`) as well as the include `content_scrolling`.

Comment: Thanks, this is awesome reply. Do you also know whats the default expanded height size of the AppBarLayout? Im trying to position the CircleImage properly and would not like to hardcode the values. Something like ?attr/actionBarSize but for the expanded toolbar?

Comment: I don't think there is a default, and I've never seen an attribute for it.  In the "Flexible space with image" example on https://material.google.com/patterns/scrolling-techniques.html#scrolling-techniques-behavior it says "Use flexible space to accommodate images in the app bar with the desired aspect ratio."  So I think you base the height on the content inside the app bar.

Comment: Everything works great but one thing... on full collapse, my circle image view disappears. Any ideas? I have checked all over everything and it all seems just like yours. I cloned your repo and yours works fine so something must be off in mine.

Comment: Oh, well... I now know app:elevation is not the same as android:elevation. I won't get that hour back. :(

Comment: @krislarson did you find a way to have the same starting position for your circle on both pre and post lollipop? I have the same issue with my behavior.

Comment: @alexbchr I revisited my project and did some digging.  The mismatch has to do with `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` and how Material Design components work with that.  IIRC, pre-Lollypop Android can't honor that setting. So measurements are a little off.  You'll see I have a `marginTop` set on the `CircleImageView` which assumes the `AppBarLayout` isn't being drawn underneath the status bar, so I think the way to fix this is to add a `@dimen/circle_offset` value to resources that is configured 220dp pre-Lollypop and 220dp minus <status bar height> for Lollypop and later.

Comment: @krislarson thanks for digging it in, for me it looked like the issue was caused by the containing fragment changing size after second layout pass. I just changed gravity of my view affected by behavior to be top instead of bottom, so now y translation is correctly calculated on first time.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to create a custom view for your `ToolBar` and hide the red dot in the `ToolBar` if it is expanded and show an `ImageView` with the red dot instead (which is hidden when the toolbar is collapsed).

You can see how to add a custom view to a `ToolBar` at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27859966/5052976

After doing this just create a `ImageView` that is visible when the `ToolBar` is expanded.

```
final CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsingToolbarLayout);
AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.appBarLayout);
appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
boolean isShow = false;
int scrollRange = -1;

@Override
public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
    if (scrollRange == -1) {
        scrollRange = appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange();
    }
    if (scrollRange + verticalOffset == 0) {
        //show toolbar dot and hide imageview dot
        isShow = true;
    } else if(isShow) {
        //hide toolbar dot and show imageview dot
        isShow = false;
    }
}
});
```

Unfortunately I can't test this right now but I think it should work ;-)